# Can I view amplify dashboard from my private cloud server?

Tags: nginx

Being a Saas app amplify just collect data from nginx instance using the agent which is installed in the same nginx machine. But I see the documentation says to see the dashboard one has to go to amplify account via internet and see them.

So here are my questions:

1. Can I view dashboard from my same nginx, amplify agent installed machine IP itself?
2. Is this data collection process not changeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me answer your questions:

Q: `Can I view dashboard from my same nginx, amplify agent installed machine IP itself?`

A: No - The NGINX Amplify is a "cloud only" product. There is no option to run it locally.

Q: `Is this data collection process not changeable?`

A: The agent is not configurable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying? is there any other mechanism approach which you can suggest for the same purpose or alternate to amplify?

Comment: sure - you can use stub_status for NGINX OSS. Use the Prometheues Exporter to export the metrics provided by the stub_status page. With Grafana you will be able to build a dashboard locally. Pretty simple setup.Let me share some Links. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html#stub_status  https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter https://prometheus.io/ https://grafana.com/